# Ability to ignore certain flagged posts and hide them from flags in tools

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, flags

The pending flag list displays all pending flags. When I take action on a flagged post, for example using the `flag or disagree...` button, the post is no longer displayed when I refresh the page, even if the moderators still haven't approved it yet.

This is a very helpful feature because it prevents me to read the questions I already flagged again and again.

There are cases where I don't feel comfortable with taking action on a specific post. May be because it's about a language or a technology I don't know. It would be helpful to have a kind of `ignore` action I can click to discard it from my list.

This is especially useful when there are thousands of flagged posts. Whenever I reload the page, chances are items I previously ignored are listed again and again on refresh.

Comment: +1, Some kind of filter on the flags would be useful - some are much easier to handle as a 10k user than others where you're almost always purely an observer.

Comment: (Although Re: the "about a language or technology I don't know" - I thought all flags were supposed to be such that moderators didn't need to be experts in a particular area to handle them)

Comment: @awoodland Sometimes there are question flagged as "low quality" or "too localized" that it's hard to judge unless you have expertise in that specific area.